# edit .fsproj file to use --standalone compiler setting

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Is it possible to change an .fsproj file (using a text editor) so that the "--standalone" compiler option is used when a build is triggered from visual studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

goto the settings of your project and open the "Build" tab - there you should see a "Other flags:" prompt. Just put your additional options there - should work.

PS: just add "--standalone" there. My testbuild grew from 13KB to over 874kb so I think it is doing it's job ;)
[image]

Comment: (Which adds an `<OtherFlags>` to the project properties in the .fsproj file.)